# Why do I get ORA-00922?

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I'm working on a little C# WPF application, in which I need to have an opportunity to create a PLAN_TABLE (I work with Oracle), but the name of the table can be customized.
So, user can type in his PLAN_TABLE name and if it doesn't exist, It will be created automatically.

Here is what I have for creating a plan table:

```
private void CreatePlanTable()
    {
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = SqlUtils.GetPlanTableScript(planTable);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Here is where I get ORA-00922 exception
        }
    }
```

SqlUtils.GetPlanTableScript() returns a string with create plan_table command, here it is:

```
    public static string GetPlanTableScript(string planTableName)
    {
        return
            new StringBuilder()
            .AppendLine($"create table \"{planTableName}\" sharing=none (")
            .AppendLine("statement_id       varchar2(30),")
            .AppendLine("plan_id            number,")
            .AppendLine("timestamp          date,")
            .AppendLine("remarks            varchar2(4000),")
            .AppendLine("operation          varchar2(30),")
            .AppendLine("options            varchar2(255),")
            .AppendLine("object_node        varchar2(128),")
            .AppendLine("object_owner       varchar2(128),")
            .AppendLine("object_name        varchar2(128),")
            .AppendLine("object_alias       varchar2(261),")
            .AppendLine("object_instance    numeric,")
            .AppendLine("object_type        varchar2(30),")
            .AppendLine("optimizer          varchar2(255),")
            .AppendLine("search_columns     number,")
            .AppendLine("id                 numeric,")
            .AppendLine("parent_id          numeric,")
            .AppendLine("depth              numeric,")
            .AppendLine("position           numeric,")
            .AppendLine("cost               numeric,")
            .AppendLine("cardinality        numeric,")
            .AppendLine("bytes              numeric,")
            .AppendLine("other_tag          varchar2(255),")
            .AppendLine("partition_start    varchar2(255),")
            .AppendLine("partition_stop     varchar2(255),")
            .AppendLine("partition_id       numeric,")
            .AppendLine("other              long,")
            .AppendLine("distribution       varchar2(30),")
            .AppendLine("cpu_cost           numeric,")
            .AppendLine("io_cost            numeric,")
            .AppendLine("temp_space         numeric,")
            .AppendLine("access_predicates  varchar2(4000),")
            .AppendLine("filter_predicates  varchar2(4000),")
            .AppendLine("projection         varchar2(4000),")
            .AppendLine("time               numeric,")
            .AppendLine("qblock_name        varchar2(128),")
            .AppendLine("other_xml          clob")
            .AppendLine(");")
            .ToString();

    }
```

This one is looking pretty stupid and I'd like to ask: if there's a better way of creating the table?

I call CreatePlanTable() from the other method, that checks the connection and existence of the plan table:

```
    public string Test(bool createPlanTable)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select 1 from all_tables where table_name = :name"; 
                
                var p = cmd.Parameters;
                p.Add("name", planTable.ToUpper());

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                isValid = reader.HasRows;
                if (isValid)
                {
                    return "Success";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (createPlanTable)
                    {
                        CreatePlanTable();
                        isValid = true;
                        return "Success";
                    }
                    return $"There is no {planTable} exists";
                }
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

So, everything works fine, when user wants to work with an existing table, but when they want me to create it, the ORA-00922 is threw. How do I avoid this exception?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you don't need own PLAN_TABLE anymore: for a long time(at least since 10.1) Oracle creates a global temporary table `SYS.PLAN_TABLE$`(granted to public) and a public synonym `PLAN_TABLE` to it by default during db creation.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove ; from the last string of create table statement:

```
   .AppendLine(")")
```

The question about any possible way of creating the table more elegantly is still open.